# Oracle APEX - issue accessing html control from a DA condition

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a custom DA that is called when JavaScript expression is document and I want it to execute only when a specific client-side condition is met.

So I set the client-side condition to javascript expression:

```
document.getElementById("myfield").options[status.selectedIndex].text != "Closed"
```

The issue is that `myfield` is no a page item, but rather an html control - a select box. So I have to use javascript expression instead of `Item != Value`.

Now when I run the page and attempt to perform the action that activates my DA, the condition is being checked and it errors out saying `Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`. How can I change my javaScript expression to get it to work?

Comment: Where is `status.selectedIndex` coming from? Have you tried something like: `$x("myfield").options[$x("myfield").selectedIndex].text != "Closed"`

Comment: sorry, should be document.getElementById("myfield").selectedIndex

Comment: Right... That's what I showed you, only rather than `document.getElementById`, I used `$x` which, in APEX, is the same thing.

Comment: Just to be sure, is this working for you now?

Comment: it works now with document.getElementByID, let me try $x...

Comment: Let me give you an "official" answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In APEX, `$x` is a shorthand reference/pointer to `document.getElementById`, so you should be able to do this:

```
$x("myfield").options[$x("myfield").selectedIndex].text != "Closed"
```

When using JavaScript expression, if you need to do more than just a basic expression, you can use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression to break down the logic. Here's an example:

```
(function(){
  var select = $x('page-item-id');

  if (select.selectedIndex === -1) {
    return false;
  }

  return select.options[select.selectedIndex].text != 'Closed'; 
})()
```

Alternatively, you could declare a function in the **Function and Global Variable Declaration** attribute of the page and then invoke it as an expression in the Condition of a DA.